# Parsing a csv file having comma separated value in single column using C

Tags: c, csv

I have to read data from CSV file and use those values in my C function.

I am doing this using below code:

```
int arg1;
char arg2[500];
int arg3;
FILE *file;
file=fopen(filename,"r");
if (file == NULL)
{
    printf("Not able to open the file\n");
}
while (fgets(line,1000, file)!=NULL)
    {
            splitline=strtok(line,",");
            while(splitline)
            {
                if(firstargument==1)
                {
                    arg1=atoi(splitline);
                    printf("First argument is %d ",arg1);
                    firstargument=2;
                }
                else if(firstargument==2)
                {
                    splitline[strlen(splitline)]='\0';
                    strcpy(arg2,splitline);
                    printf("Second argument is %s\n",arg2);
                    firstargument=3;
                }
                else
                {
                    arg3=atoi(splitline);
                    printf("Third argument is %d ",arg1);
                    firstargument=1;
                }
                splitline = strtok(NULL,",");
            }
            printf("Value to insert Key:%d,Value:%s,Height:%d\n",arg1,arg2,arg3);
            inserth(inode,arg1,arg2,arg3);
        }
```

But when my csv file's single column contains multiple comma separated values
the parsing fails

```
350206,Uma,1
350207,Umika,1
350208,"Vaishavi, Vaishnodevi",1
350226,Badriprasad,1
350227,"Kanak, Kanaka",1
```

Is there any way to read the csv file multiple values in single column?

Comment: it's not an error it's just that argument values get wrong input as
In case I read line 350227,"Kanak, Kanaka",1
my arg1 =350277
arg2="Kanak
arg3= Kanaka"
So you can see arg3 gets wrong value
correct should
arg2=Kanak, Kanaka
 arg3=1

Comment: Your parsing doesn't account for " blocks while using simple comma delimitation using ``strtok()``.

Comment: Maybe use an open source C library such as the library + CLI at https://github.com/liquidaty/zsv

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
if (file == NULL){
    perror("Not able to open the file\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
while (fgets(line,1000, file)!=NULL){
    if( 3==sscanf(line, "%d,\"%499[^\"]\",%d", &arg1, arg2, &arg3) || //pattern 1
        3==sscanf(line, "%d,%499[^,],%d",      &arg1, arg2, &arg3)){  //pattern 2
        printf("Value to insert Key:%d,Value:%s,Height:%d\n",arg1,arg2,arg3);
        inserth(inode,arg1,arg2,arg3);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid format\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to implement your own `strtok` that respects double-quotes.  `strtok` by itself is a pretty simple to implement:

```
char * tokenise( char *str, const char *delim )
{
    static char *next = NULL;
    if( str ) next = str;
    if( !*next ) return NULL;
    str = next;
    while( !strchr( delim, *next ) ) next++;
    if( *next ) *next++ = 0;
    return str;
}
```

Now, that's the general case.  You only care about commas, and in the case of double quotes, you only care about double quotes:

```
char * tokenise( char *str )
{
    static char *next = NULL;
    if( str ) next = str;
    if( !*next ) return NULL;
    str = next;

    if( *str == '"' ) {
       str++;
       next++;
       while( *next && *next != '"' ) next++;
       if( *next == '"' ) *next++ = 0;
    }

    while( *next && *next != ',' ) next++;
    if( *next ) *next++ = 0;
    return str;
}
```

This is pretty naive, but should do the trick.  It detects `"` in the first character, removes it and then scans to the next `"`.  It doesn't handle escaped quotes, whitespace between CSV fields, or syntax errors (such as non-comma characters appearing after a closing quote -- it will drop them) but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for a csv file, if a comma comes inside double quotes, it ususally means the comma should be ignored. This means that every row has only 3 values (3 columns).

Since you have only two types of rows, one with double quotes and one without double quotes, as simple if-else statement would help here

I am using `strsep` instead of `strtok`. Also I am reading from the file line by line.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

    {
    FILE *file;
    char *splitline;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    file=fopen(filename,"r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
    printf("Not able to open the file\n");
    }
     while ((read = getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1) 
        {
            if(strstr(line,"\"") != NULL)

            {
            printf("%s\n",line);
                    splitline=strsep(&line,",");
                printf("%s : %s\n",splitline,line);
                    line = line+1;  // avoiding first doublequotes("), you may use strsep twice instead
                    splitline = strsep(&line,"\"");
                printf("%s : %s\n",splitline,line);
                    line = line+1;   // removing comma and rest is the 3rd entry
                printf("%s",line);
                     }

                   else
                  {


                   //Routine code that expects two commas and three values

                   }

          }
    }
```